# How to mask an image with another b/w image in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, image-manipulation, jimp

So I want to mask this image
[image]
with this image
[image]

which will result in this image
[image]

**How to do this in NodeJS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be pretty easy. We just need to use the **[JIMP](https://npmjs.com/jimp)** package for NodeJS.
We can output the image as a file or a buffer to use in canvas too.

```js
var Jimp = require('jimp');
Jimp.read(image_1,(err, image) => {
  Jimp.read(image_2,(err1,image1) => {
    image1.resize(image.bitmap.width,image.bitmap.height)
    image.mask(image1,0,0)
    image.write(output_image) //for a file output

//for buffer output
    image.getBufferAsync('image/png'); //for transparent image use image/png
  })
})
```